# Seleccionar un directorio con WindowBuilder de Java

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica

Estaba pensando en hacer una especie de programa donde se seleccionaría un directorio de windows para posteriormente renombrar todos los ficheros de dentro de acuerdo a un patrón predefinido.

No pretendo que se me de el código, sólo si alguien puede decirme si seria posible hacer algo así y si pudiera ser decirme la manera más o menos en la que se haría.. He visto que hay una clase que sirve para renombrar archivos, pero no tengo ni idea si se podría seleccionar un directorio para después actuar con sus ficheros.

PD: Tenía intención de hacerlo mediante [windowbuilder](/questions/tagged/windowbuilder) para que sea más gráfico, aunque si tiene que ser con otra opción no hay problema.

Comment: Lamentablemente esta pregunta es muy amplia y seguramente será cerrada. Pero la respuesta es que sí se puede hacer lo que dices. Windows Builder sólo te servirá para hacer la ventana pero la lógica de lo que quieres hacer te tocará picar aunque es sencillo si lo piensas un poco y ves la documentación de java.

Comment: Yo te recomendaría que si tienes algo de código edites la pregunta y lo agregues.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba esto. para obtener los Files de un directorio especificado , aplicando el filter. `isFile`, luego se recorre el array para hacer el cambio de nombre.
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FilenameFilter;
    import java.util.Arrays;

```
public class Solution {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path= "ruta";
        File file = new File(path);
        String[] directories = file.list(new FilenameFilter() {
          @Override
          public boolean accept(File current, String name) {
            return new File(current,name).isFile();
          }
        });
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(directories));
        File var,newvar;int i=1;
        for (String directory : directories) {
            var = new File(path+directory);
            newvar= new File(path+"newName -"+i);
            var.renameTo(newvar);
        }
    }

}
```